# What were four objects seen in Flightradar24 over Germany with the callsign TWR?

Tags: aircraft-identification, flightradar24

In Flightradar24 from 290030Z and then for two more hours, there were 4 identical objects over Germany between EDFM and EDDS at altitudes from 600 to 1900 feet, a few knots speed and each changing course more than two times per minute but no trace like if stationary. The distance between the objects was about 20km. They all have the same callsign: "TWR". What are they?

Comment: Keep in mind FR24 is essentially a huge number of hobby receivers picking up basically anything transmitted on 1090 MHz and then trying to associate those signals with a known database of flights. It is not always accurate. Many flights are not shown, and sometimes something is shown that does not actually exist

Comment: @expeditedescent, or, in this case, apparently on 868 MHz.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is this squawk 7777 target at an altitude of 62,700' over Germany?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/75159/what-is-this-squawk-7777-target-at-an-altitude-of-62-700-over-germany)

Answer (score 3):

Many towers in Germany are equipped with [FLARM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FLARM) so that they are electronically visible to FLARM equipped aircraft in the area. This is especially useful for helicopter emergency medical services and law enforcement that operate in urban areas during marginal weather conditions.

The fact that the towers are not always visible on FR24 may have to do with the fact that not all their receivers are equipped with FLARM. If nobody nearby is providing FLARM data to FR24, the towers are not visible on FR24.

The speed shown has to do with the GPS receiver in the FLARM unit; they sometimes detect small speeds, even though the receiver is stationary.

Comment: Perhaps the speed is due to tower sway getting picked up by the GPS?