# What is this squawk 7777 target at an altitude of 62,700' over Germany?

Tags: aircraft-identification

Can anyone shed any light as to what this is (circled in white)?

[image]

Answer (score 36):

This is a military test transponder, not a real aircraft. The callsign GAFTT08 stands for **German Air Force Test Transponder** 08. When you zoom in on the map, you can see the reconstructed position move in a pattern around the fixed true position:

[image: GAFTT08]
<sup>([adsbexchange.com](https://tar1090.adsbexchange.com/))</sup>

As far as I can tell, the military does not publicly say what exactly they are doing here. The only sources I could find are from forums:

> GAFTTxx = German Air Force Test Transponder

<sup>([flugzeugforum.de](https://www.flugzeugforum.de/threads/flugbetrieb-in-wittmund-etnt-2019.91679/page-30#post-2627979))</sup>

> German Air Force Test Transponder. So not an aircraft, not a drone. Don’t know why it is online all the time, but it is. Sometimes over Würzburg, sometimes over Ingolstadt.

<sup>([forum.scramble.nl](https://forum.scramble.nl/viewtopic.php?p=956375))</sup>

Additionally, the squawk code of 7777 is used in Germany for fixed test transponders according to Wikipedia (thanks to ymb1 for pointing this out):

> **7777** US, Germany, Belgium, Netherlands: Non-discrete code used by fixed test transponders (RABMs) to check correctness of radar stations (BITE)

<sup>([List of transponder codes - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_transponder_codes))</sup>

This is also confirmed by the following ICAO definition:

> Code 7700 is reserved for recognizing an aircraft
>   in emergency. (Codes 7711 to 7717 and 7721 to 7727 are
>   reserved for SAR operations and code **7777 for monitoring
>   the ground transponder**.)

<sup>([ICAO - SSR CODE ASSIGNMENT SYSTEM](https://www.icao.int/NACC/Documents/eDOCS/ATM/ORCAM%20CAR%20SAM%20-%20SSR%20Codes%20en.pdf), emphasis mine)</sup>

Comment: Test transponders are used to verify the accuracy of radar data. They are known to always be in a fixed position (the movement you see is probably due to inaccuracy of ADS-B Exchange). Controllers or technicians will periodically check that the reply from the test transponder is within a defined range of the expected position.

Comment: It is not moving in a pattern, the multilateration system used to calculate its position has pattern in it's position errors.

Comment: @J.Hougaard & DeltaLima Thanks, I clarified in the answer what the movement is.

Answer (score 3):

It is a test transponder for the German Air force. According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identification_friend_or_foe), it is a test for the friend or foe identification system. So, basically they are testing technology to identify aircraft, so they can aviod friendly fire in battle situations. It is not a real aircraft.

Comment: I don't see "test transponder" or "7777" mentioned anywhere in that Wikipedia article. Could you clarify what makes you think it has anything to do with an IFF system?

Comment: @J.Hougaard scroll down -> squawk code -> scroll down .. find 
"7777 US, Germany, Belgium, Netherlands Non-discrete code used by fixed test transponders (RABMs) to check correctness of radar stations (BITE)"

Comment: [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_transponder_codes) should be the wiki page linked - people shouldn't have to follow the breadcrumbs.

Comment: @eagle275 Still doesn't appear to have anything to do with an IFF system

Comment: And it does not have. Military transponders are different. This is purely for ATC (even if used by military too).